# Android Firebase cloud messagin: Will push messages become lost?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

In case subscriber to a topic is not online at time of sending push notification to that topic/subscriber, will message for him/her become lost or they get their message when they get online?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on the payload you need to send. Look into the [Lifetime of a Message](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#lifetime) for more details.

Normally, it will be queued in the FCM servers and will be sent as soon as the device goes online.